# Permanent block of IP after n retries using fail2ban

Tags: fail2ban

I have a fail2ban configured like below:

- block the ip after 3 failed attempts
- release the IP after 300 sec timeout

This works perfectly and I want to keep it this way such that a valid user gets a chance to retry the login after the timeout.  Now, I want to implement a rule where if same IP is been detected as attack and blocked, unblocked 5 times, permanently block the IP and never unblock again.  Can this be achieved with fail2ban alone or I need to write my own script to do that?

I am doing this in centos.

Comment: It's a rather silly idea - the more rules you add to iptables the slower it gets.

Comment: Appreciate your comment but what I need is an answer and not a suggestion.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sometimes the right answer to "how do I do X" is "don't do X".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Before 0.11, there was [no default feature or a setting within fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban:Community_Portal#Permanently_Ban_Persistent_IP_Addresses) to achieve this. But starting with the upcoming 0.11 release, ban time is [automatically calculated](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/71) and increases exponentially with each new offense which, on the long term, will mean a more or less permanent block.

Until then, your best approach is probably setting up [fail2ban to monitor its own log file](http://whyscream.net/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban_monitoring_Fail2ban). It is a two step process...

### Step 1

We could need to **create a filter** to check for **BAN**'s in the log file (fail2ban's log file)

### Step 2

We need to **define the jail**, similar to the following...

```
[fail2ban]
enabled = true
filter = fail2ban
action = iptables-allports[name=fail2ban]
logpath = /path/to/fail2ban.log
# findtime: 1 day
findtime = 86400
# bantime: 1 year
bantime = 31536000
```

Technically, it is **not a permanent block**, but only blocks for a year (that we can increase too).

Anyway, for your question (Can this be achieved with fail2ban alone or I need to write my own script to do that?)... writing own script might work well. Setting up the script to extract the *frequently* banned IPs and then putting them into `/etc/hosts.deny` is what I'd recommend.

Comment: Adding to this excellent answer... Depending on how logging and MaxAuthTries are configured for `sshd_config`, this could potentially only block 3 failed logins for a sshd "session" - not 3 failed logins provided.

For example, by default an attacker could try ['pass1', 'pass2', 'pass3'] in a single session before sshd disconnects.  Depending on how sshd is set to log, this could appear as 1, 2 or 3 attempts to fail2ban.

Comment: There's the fail2ban recidive filter for that, now.

Comment: What do you mean by *upcoming 0.11 release*? The most recent seems to be 10.3.1: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/releases

Comment: I hope you meant **0.10.3.1**. You can track the progress of "0.11" at https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.11 . Basically, it is not released, yet!

Answer (score 39):

I believe if you put `bantime = -1` in that config section, it is a permanent block.

Comment: Indeed, setting `bantime` to any negative value is a permanent ban (as of Fail2Ban ver. 0.6.1 (2006/03/16))

Comment: adding -1 to settings made fail2ban unresponsive

Answer (score 15):

Phil Hagen wrote an excellent article on this subject.
"[Permanently Ban Repeat Offenders With fail2ban](http://stuffphilwrites.com/2013/03/permanently-ban-repeat-offenders-fail2ban/)".

His suggestion is the same as Pothi but provides a step by step guide.

This included:

- separate ban list by jail (ip.blocklist.ssh, ip.blocklist.xxx)
- **ban lists autoloaded if service restart** (main advantage of this method imho)
- email notification if repeater engaged.

Answer (score 9):

fail2ban has already a jail to ban recidive. If you watch `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`, you will found :

```
# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers
# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local
#   is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into
#   an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines
[recidive]

enabled  = false
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5
```

## How to add in jail.local ?

```
[recidive]
enabled  = true
bantime  = 31536000  ; 1 year
findtime = 18144000  ; 1 month
maxretry = 2
```

For check you loglevel you can do : `fail2ban-client get loglevel`.

- **set loglevel MYLEVEL** : sets logging level to MYLEVEL. Levels: CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, NOTICE, INFO, DEBUG
- More [command on the wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Commands).

With old version of fail2ban, you can get [this bug](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/858).

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Chin's answer this is pretty simple. Just edit the 2 settings in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` to match your preferences.

```
 # ban time in seconds. Use -1 for forever. Example is 1 week.
 bantime  = 604800
 # number of failures before banning
 maxretry = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to vim, open /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

and just modify after `fail2ban service restart`:

```
# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = ***1296000***

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime  = ***60000***

# "maxretry" is the number of failures before a host get banned.
maxretry = ***3***
```