# fail2ban doesnt permanently block

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-12.04, fail2ban

Fail2ban doesn't seem to block permanently.

I have bantime =-1 but if i look a bit later on my iptables its just not there anymore all ill see is

```
Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Why is this happening if i set it to -1, is there something else i need to configure?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fail2ban but it seems it just adds rules to iptables. It's not reboot-resistant

Comment: Yeah but i havent rebooted my computer since which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Fail2ban doesn't have a feature to permanently block.

See http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban%3aCommunity_Portal#Permanently_Ban_Persistent_IP_Addresses and http://whyscream.net/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban_monitoring_Fail2ban for more information.

Comment: So why does it say -1 in the config will make it permanent

Comment: @soniccool That [depends on the version of fail2ban](http://serverfault.com/questions/415040/permanent-block-of-ip-after-n-retries-using-fail2ban).  Setting a nice long expiry time - like a year - is the usual solution. Alternatively, store "permabans" in a separate file/iptables rule.

Comment: Got it alright! I guess a year will do haha

Comment: If you're happy with my solution you're able to upvote or choose this answer as being the most correct/useful one.